# js заменить подстроку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строк с текстом, хочу в ней поменять цвет:

```
bgimg.replace("grey","white");
```

но в итоге получаю ошибку **main.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined(…)**

Как можно без проблем заменить подстроку на другую?

Comment: А почему просто не сменить свойство типа : bgimg.colour = "white"; ? А не срабатывать может потому что bgimg это не текст, если там точно текст то можно сделать bgimg.toString().replace("grey","white");

Comment: Что такое `bgimg`? Что выдает `typeof bgimg`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, очевидно же - `undefined`.

Comment: Вы не у строки пытаетесь заменить текст.

Comment: `(bgimg || '').replace("grey","white");`

Answer (score 0):

Как верно указал @Other, вам стоит проверить что bgimg определенн в текущей области видимости и наследует метод replace от String. Судя по тому что вы указали, у вас не определен bgimg и поэтому метод replace нельзя применить к undefined.